# Mongoid Rails 5 convert string with multiple arguments to symbolized value for order_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a controller method where I'm trying to pass a string with multiple `order_by` arguments to return a sorted collection.

The order_by syntax works with one stringified argument,
i.e.

```
order_param = "image_fize_size DESC"

query.order_by(order_param)

>> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {...},
options: {:sort => {"image_file_size"=> -1}}
class: ...>
```

Due to mongoid transforming the string behind the scenes

Is there a certain syntax I can use to pass multiple arguments as one string to the `order_by` method without any complex string manipulation required?
i.e.

```
order_param = "image_file_size DESC created_at DESC"

query.order_by(order_param)
# to hopefully yield a criteria that looks like:
>> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {...},
options: {:sort => {"image_file_size"=> -1, "created_at" => -1 }}
class: ...>
```

Comment: Something like this should work: `query.order('image_file_size desc, created_at asc')` (almost exactly what you would like to have, just with a missing comma separator added) ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/reference/queries/#ordering))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to affect multiple sorts using order_by!

```
irb(main):001:0> query.order_by("image_file_size DESC, created_at DESC")
```

Some other ways:

```
irb(main):002:0> query.order_by(image_file_size: :desc, created_at: :desc)

irb(main):003:0> query.order_by(image_file_size: "desc", created_at: "desc")

irb(main):004:0> query.order_by(image_file_size: -1, created_at: -1)

irb(main):006:0> query.order_by([:image_file_size, -1], [:created_at, -1])
(This also accepts "desc", :desc)

irb(main):007:0> query.order_by(:image_file_size.desc, :created_at.desc)
=> 
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {:sort=>{"image_file_size"=>-1, "created_at"=>-1}}
  class:    ...
  embedded: ...>
```

EDIT: Check out the [API docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/master/api/Mongoid/Criteria/Queryable/Optional.html#order_by-instance_method) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.
The documentation on this method was pretty scarce

Comment: We put a lot of effort into documenting the methods themselves... If you look at the API docs the use cases are pretty expansive in this case: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/master/api/Mongoid/Criteria/Queryable/Optional.html#order_by-instance_method